# "Call to a member function library() on null" when use Library Upload Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-4

when i upload my file, i got error like this "Call to a member function library() on null"... why?

this is My View

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>File PDF</label>
            <form method="post" id="form-upload" action="<?= base_url(); ?>/panduan/testing" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="type_proses" id="type_proses" />
            <input type="hidden" name="type_file" id="type_file" />
            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="file" required accept=".pdf" /></p>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

this is my Controller

```
public function testing()
{
    $file_name = 'tes';
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'/public/assets-menu/file/upload/panduan/';
    $config['file_name'] = $file_name;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        print_r('error');
    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        print_r('ok');       
    }
}
```

My Construct

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->panduan_model = new \App\Models\M_Panduan();
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the class definition and constructor definition?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, perhaps you miss this line in construct

```
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct(); //don't forget this line
$this->panduan_model = new \App\Models\M_Panduan();
}
```

Comment: thanks guys, i have tried and it doesnt work,, in the end i used php move()